# Will a DI-Container help this situation

Tags: wpf, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I writing a document editor of sorts. The application is written in WPF and needs to be able to handle multiple documents within the same process. Each document has its own editor window with is own Ribbon (kinda like the way Word does it).

I would like to use DI patterns in the application, so f.ex. a "SaveManager" class could be injected with the document it is supposed to save. Obviously the container can't create the whole object graph at application start up, because the user may choose to open or create a new document at a later time. The "normal" way to handle this, is to use an abstract factory, but does that means i need a factory for every class that operates on the document. I'm expecting a lot of classes will need a reference to the document and I don't want to jump through hoops just for the sake of DI. Is there a way to let the container manage the documents life-time, handing out the right document instance at the right time.

Best regards,
Terje

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended doing was to create a child container per document. That way the I isolated the resolvement of each document window to its own container.

/terje

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you go like this:

1. Make base class which is somesort of bootstrap and builder for the environment
2. Put everything that is the same on all documents except the specifics
3. Create concrete classes that implement specifics of particular documents
4. Use DI on the base class for common references to be injected on build up
5. Use interfaces for specific references on specific classes like:

   void MyClass(IResource resource);
6. Inherit from that resource on other classes and then resolve it by using generics or typecasting on concrete classes

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm not sure i fully understand your suggestion, but it got me thinking in other direction than i originally did, and i appreciate that.